# Splitting text values in Power Pivots

Tags: powerpivot

In my current non-power pivot method, I have a formula here to try and extract the latest sprint from Jira data:

=INDEX(SORT(TEXTSPLIT(AC2,,";")),ROWS(TEXTSPLIT(AC2,,";")))

The data might look like:   Sprint1;Sprint3;Sprint2
The idea is I get the "latest" sprint back (Sprint3)
This would split them:
Sprint1
Sprint3
Sprint2

Then resort them and provide the last item in the list (Sprint3).

I'm trying to move to Power Pivots, because with the above method I have to keep copying/pasting that formula (as well as others).

But I can't yet figure out how to split the row out, or achieve the same thing in PowerPivots.  Neither ROWS or TEXTSPLIT seem to exist in DAX functions.

Any ideas ?